# Linear Searching for name in Python sorted List of names

Tags: python

Consider the following incomplete function:

```
def linear_search_sorted(names, search_name):
    for name in names:
            ...
    return False
```

The above function takes a list of sorted names and a target name as parameters and searches for the given name in the parameter sorted list. The function returns `True` if the search value is present in the list, and `False` otherwise. Complete the above function above so that it also returns the total number of elements and total number of equality comparisons (i.e. using ==) needed to search for the given name.

```
def linear_search_sorted(names, search_name):
    length = len(names)
    comp = 0
    for name in names:
        comp += 1
        if name == search_name: 
            return (True, length,comp)
        
        elif name[0] == search_name[0]:
            return (False, length, comp)
    return (False,length, comp)
```

Test1:

```
result = linear_search_sorted(['Abby', 'Bella', 'Charlotte', 'Daisy', 'Ella', 'Faith', 'Grace', 'Hannah'], 'Bella')
print('Found: {} Length: {} Comparisons: {}'.format(result[0], result[1], result[2]))
```

output1:

```
Expected ->   Found: True Length: 8 Comparisons: 2
Got ->        Found: True Length: 8 Comparisons: 2
```

Test2:

```
result = linear_search_sorted(['Abby', 'Bella', 'Charlotte', 'Daisy', 'Ella', 'Faith', 'Grace', 'Hannah'], 'Natalie')
print('Found: {} Length: {} Comparisons: {}'.format(result[0], result[1], result[2]))
```

Output2:

```
Expected ->    Found: False Length: 8 Comparisons: 8
Got ->         Found: False Length: 8 Comparisons: 8
```

Test3:

```
result = linear_search_sorted(['Abby', 'Bella', 'Charlotte', 'Daisy', 'Ella', 'Faith', 'Grace', 'Hannah', 'Isabella', 'Jade', 'Kate', 'Lily', 'Maddison', 'Natalie', 'Olivia', 'Phoebe', 'Queen', 'Rebecca', 'Samantha'], 'Ethan')
print('Found: {} Length: {} Comparisons: {}'.format(result[0], result[1], result[2]))
```

Output3:

```
Expected ->    Found: False Length: 19 Comparisons: 6
Got ->         Found: False Length: 19 Comparisons: 5
```

I know that for Test3, the `search_name` is 'Ethan' so the function should work in a way that it compares upto 'Faith' because the list is sorted and after Faith, Ethan(starts with E) cannot be found. But I don't know how do I make my comparisons go upto that point. Can someone help.

Comment: Without knowing your usecase, is there a reason why you even use linear search on a sorted list? Maybe binary search is the way to go? You can have a look at the built-in `bisect` module for binary search: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the intention of this code should check if the first letter is greater, not equal, to the searched name.

So:

```
def linear_search_sorted(names, search_name):
    length = len(names)
    comp = 0
    for name in names:
        comp += 1
        if name == search_name: 
            return (True, length,comp)
        
        elif name[0] > search_name[0]:
            return (False, length, comp)
    return (False,length, comp)
```

This returns all your expected results.

Comment: You also can compare whole strings, not just characters. In fact comparing whole strings is done characterwise. So you can even use: `elif name > search_name:`

Answer (score 0):

You increment *comp* for every name in the input list. You should only increment it when you test for equality.

```
def linear_search_sorted(names, search_name):
    count = 0
    for name in names:
        if name > search_name:
            break
        count += 1
        if name == search_name:
            return True, len(names), count
    return False, len(names), count


print(linear_search_sorted(['Abby', 'Bella', 'Charlotte', 'Daisy', 'Ella', 'Faith', 'Grace', 'Hannah', 'Isabella', 'Jade', 'Kate', 'Lily', 'Maddison', 'Natalie', 'Olivia', 'Phoebe', 'Queen', 'Rebecca', 'Samantha'], 'Ethan'))
```

So the output should be:

```
(False, 19, 5)
```

...because we test for equality 5 times (Abby -> Ella). Once we get to Faith we know that Ethan cannot be found due to the lexical > comparison